# Calling a static function from the generic base class of an array of types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Why wouldnt the following work?

Assuming `System.Type[] allGUIMenuTypes` is defined is the base class is Defined as

```
public class GUIMenu<T>
```

And I want to use it like this pseudocode: (Edit: I dont know what mod put this line here but it is not pseudocode, it is actual code)

```
allGUIMenuTypes.ForEach(t => GUIMenu<t>.Close());
```

(Dont pay any attention to the "fake" linq style ForEach, My question is pertaining to `GUIMenu<t>`)

Alternatively I also tried to invoke this static function using reflection and got stuck trying to figure out what the rest of the parameters should be....

```
allGUIMenuTypes.ForEach(T => T.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                                  .InvokeMember("Close", 
                                  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public......
```

Basically to explain myself further, I have an array of Types whose base type is 
the generic class `GUIMenu<T>`. I need to call the static function `Close()` from the base class of each of those types.

Comment: Which class defines `Close()`?

Comment: You should really just introduce a non-generic base class or interface that GUIMenu<T> implements.

Comment: Post a sample which reproduces the problem. that will help us to help you back

Comment: ....BaseType.InvokeMember("Close", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null, null, null);

Comment: obviously something is wrong with app logic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
class BaseClass<T>
{
    public static void Close()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

class Derived1 : BaseClass<int>  { }

class Derived2 : BaseClass<double> { }
```

The following reflection approach works:

```
var types = new[] {typeof(Derived1), typeof(Derived2)};

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var method = type.BaseType.GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```